# How to place borders between lines of a wrapping, horizontal multi-line menu?

Tags: css, menu, border

I have a menu, based on nested, unordered lists. All styling and display is done via css.

The menu is wrapped in a fixed-width div. For some top-level items, the submenu contains too many items for one line and these wrap onto a second or even third line, expanding the div height. This works fine.

What I am trying to do is to add a horizontal line/divider/border between the rows of submenu items, irrespective of the number of rows, and equal in width to either the row below or above (preferably below). Obviously, no line will be present if there is only one row of items.

I tried to add a background along the top of the entire `<ul id="submenu">` and then remove it from just the first line using `ul#submenu:first-line{}`, then realised that this cannot be done (headslap).

I then altered the structure of the menu to use `<p>` elements nested in divs, again using `div#submenu:first-line{}`, but testing this gives me strange results. For example, a background colour will show in the first line, but only half the height of the submenu items; background images appear halfway up the submenu items. Sometimes nothing shows until I click on the current top level menu item.

I even tried replacing the list structure with a single `<p>` element, containing a series of `<a>` elements, and got the same results.

The evidence suggests that I am not using the `:first-line` pseudo-element properly, but reading around the web suggests that this should work.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong and how to get these horizontal lines, preferably with CSS and without JS?

Here's my code:

```
#subMenuContainer {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#subMenu {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ddd;
}
#sub {
    border-top:2px solid green;
    padding:0px;
    line-height:30px;
}
#sub::first-line {
    border-top:2px solid red; /* doesn't work */
    background-color:pink; /* works */
    color:yellow; /* doesn't work */
}
#sub p {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
}
#sub p a {
    padding:0px 0px;
    line-height:1em;
}​
<div id="subMenuContainer">
    <div id="subMenu">
        <div id="sub" >
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem1</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem2</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem3</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem4</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem5</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem6</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem7</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem8</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem9</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">MenuItem10</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And [the same in jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KhnBT/4/)

Comment: Try creating an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see what you are trying to accomplish & what you have thus far

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, Lübnah, @Vaze. Here is my example marked up as divs and paragraphs: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KhnBT/4/)

Comment: Still no answer to this. Anybody?...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the :first-child rather than the :first-line pseudo class.

- :first-line refers to the first line of a text element
- :first-child refers to the first child element of a parent. e.g. the first li in your ul.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp for more details.

If that doesn't sort you out, can you post your markup?

V.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Vaze. I'm not sure that this will work, as there are several child elements per row (assuming the row is wider than the elements). However, I will give it a shot and will post my markup in a couple of hours once home.